# How do I generate a Dashboard PDF file using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have the need to export the dashboard to a PDF file. Some charts on it are easy enough to display by translating them into a picture. But some charts contain text and some charts contain a table which also needs to be displayed as text.

The main point, where I stopped, is how to get the embedded text and how to properly spell the styles and spacing.

Example HTML

```
            <div
              class="dashboard-component dashboard-component-chart-holder"
            >
              <h1>COVID-19 Vaccine Dashboard</h1>
              <p>
                Everywhere you look, you see negative news about COVID-19. This
                is to be expected; it''s been a brutal year and this disease is
                no joke. This dashboard hopes to use visualization to inject
                some optimism about the coming return to normalcy we enjoyed
                before 2020! There''s lots to be optimistic about:
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  the sheer volume of attempts to fund the R&amp;D needed to
                  produce and bring an effective vaccine to market
                </li>
                <li>
                  the large number of countries involved in at least one vaccine
                  candidate (and the diversity of economic status of these
                  countries)
                </li>
                <li>the diversity of vaccine approaches taken</li>
                <li>
                  the fact that 2 vaccines have already been approved (and a
                  hundreds of thousands of patients have already been
                  vaccinated)
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h3>The Dataset</h3>
              <p>
                This dashboard is powered by data maintained by the Millken
                Institute (
                <a href="#">
                  link to dataset
                </a>
                ). We researched each vaccine candidate and added our own best
                guesses for the country responsible for each vaccine effort.
              </p>
              <p>
                <em>Note that this dataset was last updated on 07/2021</em>.
              </p>
            </div>
```

how it looks

[image]